# Can anyone identify the font in this infographic?

Tags: font-identification

Can anyone can identify the font used for each section title, i.e. "Paranormal," "Conspiracy," "Quackery," etc. in [this graphic](https://imgur.com/a/knILO), titled "An Organized Collection of Irrational Nonsense":

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Try 2

Getting the original from [Imgur](https://imgur.com/a/knILO), I guess the font is [PF Beau Sans Pro Black](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/parachute/pf-beau-sans-pro/black/):

[image]

Some more previews:

[image]

---

#### Previous Attempts!

This looks like either **Calibri** or **Ubuntu**, or may be **Cocon**:

#### Calibri

[image]

#### Ubuntu

[image]

#### Cocon

[image]

Comment: The uppercase U is different to the sample, although these are all good alternatives!

Comment: Yeah, I am trying to find the font. But these were the ones, I feel they are quite similar!

Comment: I feel the `U` is some kind of flavour of ubuntu.

Comment: Awesome Praveen! Thanks! Would you mind letting me know if you used an online tool that helped you with your search? Would be nice to check that first before bothering you kind folks on GD.

Comment: Yes @Addikt, it was WhatTheFont from MyFonts! :)

Answer (score 6):

I'm the guy who made **An Organized Collection of Irrational Nonsense**, so I can confirm the font used for the set titles is **PF Beau Sans** Black.

In the newest version of the image below, I changed most of the smaller fonts to **Fira Sans** Regular for readability.

[image]

"All the Crazy, Whackaddodle..." is **Titillium** Semibold.

Comment: this should be the correct answer, welcome to the community!

Comment: Thanks for this awesome infographic mate! `:)`

Comment: @Luciano Yep, agreed. It was solved two years ago. What's a help that's not timely. I don't deny this person, all credits should go to the author. Just saying.